# MySQL DELAYED vs LOW_PRIORITY - what is the difference?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Is there any difference between:

```
INSERT DELAYED INTO tableA SET val='1'
```

and

```
INSERT LOW_PRIORITY INTO tableA SET val='1'
```

both are supported by the [official MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

and there is a [dedicated section to INSERT DELAYED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-delayed.html)

This section says that DELAYED is planned for removal in future releases.

> DELAYED inserts and replaces were deprecated in MySQL 5.6. In MySQL
>   5.7, DELAYED is not supported. The server recognizes but ignores the DELAYED keyword, handles the insert as a nondelayed insert, and
>   generates an ER_WARN_LEGACY_SYNTAX_CONVERTED warning (“INSERT DELAYED
>   is no longer supported. The statement was converted to INSERT”). The
>   DELAYED keyword is scheduled for removal in a future release.

So apart from this I wonder if there is any difference?

Also, I have to say I use InnoDB in MySQL, not MyISAM. Is there actually any advantage with DELAYED INSERTs?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer:  Neither is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html says:

> LOW_PRIORITY affects only storage engines that use only table-level locking (such as MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE).

Since you're using InnoDB, `LOW_PRIORITY` has no effect. It wouldn't have any benefit anyway, because in InnoDB, writers do not block readers, and vice-versa.